# How to connect HTML & Google Sheet and then display row values based on user input in HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to connect HTML & Google Sheet. I have some sample codes below but I don't know how to **connect** them together. Could anyone point out to me how can I change below code to make it work for me?

Below codes are trying to display a HTML page for users to input ID Number and then get the latest row of related data from Google Sheet. Thank you.

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">  
        <label for="idNum">ID Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idNum">
        <output id="rnum"></output>
      </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" id="searchbtn">Search Profile</button>
   </div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("searchbtn").addEventListener("click", searchProfile);
   function searchProfile(){
     var appProfile = document.getElementById("idNum").value;
     if(appProfile.length === 6){
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProfile).updateIdNum(appProfile);
     } 
     //else{
     //alert("invalid Profile Number");
     }   
   function updateProfile(returnData){
      document.getElementById("rnum").value = returnData[1];
   }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Apps Script inside Google Sheet:

```js
function updateIdNum(appProfile){
  //  var appProfile = "101018"

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Results");

  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var dJoin = data.join().split(",");
  var myPnum = dJoin.indexOf(appProfile);
  var dataRow = ws.getRange(myPnum + 1, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(dataRow[0]);

  if (myPnum > -1){
    return dataRow[0];
  } else {
    Logger.log("unknown")
    //return "unavailable";
  } 
}


function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
  .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .showSidebar(html);
}
```

Google Sheet data look like:

```html
ID Number | First Name | Last Name|
101018    | John       | Doe      |
101011    | Jane       | Doe      |
```

Comment: About `but I don't know how to connect them together.`, can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script? Because when I saw your script, for example, when `101018` is put to the input tag and click the button, `John` is put to `<output id="rnum"></output>`. How about this?

Comment: HTML input requires 6 digit like 101018, and HTML should output "John" and "Doe" respectively.
I am new to Apps Scripts, so I have no idea how HTML calls Apps Scripts to get that row of value by inputing in HTML.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `HTML should output "John" and "Doe" respectively`, in this case, how about modifying `document.getElementById("rnum").value = returnData[1];` to ``document.getElementById("rnum").value = `${returnData[1]}, ${returnData[2]}`;``? And about `I have no idea how HTML calls Apps Scripts to get that row of value by inputing in HTML`, I think that your script retrieves the value from Google Apps Script. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: The current issue is I don't see any sample HTML code is calling sample Apps Scripts code. Therefore I am confused how does it work? (Yep, it is not working)
How can I modify both HTML & Apps Scripts to make it works?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Dear Tanaike, you are welcome. My issue is I want to write a HTML page for users to input "ID Number" to search the row result of Google Sheet. As you can see, "ID Number" is the unique key. The concept is like vlookup in Excel. 
However, I am not sure how to perform it? Thank you.

Comment: `My issue is I want to write a HTML page for users to input "ID Number" to search the row result of Google Sheet`, about that, your code already does that. It searches for the ID number and returns the first name on the sidebar. Can you clarify what is the issue?

Comment: I know it searches for the ID. But how to link html to get Google Sheet please?

Comment: `But how to link html to get Google Sheet please? `, your HTML and Sheets is already linked. Otherwise the correct result wouldn't show in the sidebar. Perhaps what you are referring to `link` has another meaning in this context. Please provide an example of the expected/desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying Data from table in html dialog

GS:

```
function getMyData() {
  return [["ID Number","First Name","Last Name"],[101018,"John","Doe"],[101011,"Jane","Doe"]];
}

function launchThisDialog() {
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ah1").evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(t,"Display Table");
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabledata">
       <? var vs = getMyData(); ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```